# Cannot switch to intended frame when timer is added in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

The sequence should be

1. show firstframe
2. click "continue"
3. show secondframe
4. wait 5 seconds
5. show third frame

so I added .after() in the continue button, but if I added the timer, the firstframe will wait for 5 seconds after clicking "continue" then switches to thirdframe skipping secondframe. But if I do not the button will simply switch to second frame.

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

h= int(app.winfo_screenheight())
w= int(app.winfo_screenwidth())

firstframe= Frame(app,width= w,height=h)
firstframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

firstcanvas= Canvas(firstframe, width =w, height = h,bg='yellow')
firstcanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 

firstcanvas.create_text(1000,500,text="WELCOME!!!",font=("Monttserat", 100))

secondframe= Frame(app,width= w,height=h)
secondframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

secondcanvas= Canvas(secondframe, width =w, height = h,bg='blue')
secondcanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 

secondcanvas.create_text(1000,500,text="Please Wait",font=("Monttserat", 100))

thirdframe= Frame(app,width= w,height=h)
thirdframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

thirdcanvas= Canvas(thirdframe, width =w, height = h,bg='red')
thirdcanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0) 

thirdcanvas.create_text(1000,500,text="You May Start",font=("Monttserat", 100))



def switch(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

    
def secondframetimer():
    switch(secondframe)
    app.after(5000, switch(thirdframe))  #just uncomment/ comment this line
    
    
buttoncontinue = Button(firstframe, highlightthickness=0, text="Continue", font= ("Monttserat", 35,"bold"), border=0,command=lambda: secondframetimer())
buttoncontinue.place(x=800,y=620,width=300,height =50)

def key_pressed(event):
    if event.char=='q' or event.char=='Q':
        print("key ",event.char)
        app.destroy()
        
app.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
app.bind('<Key>',key_pressed)
switch(firstframe)  
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `after()` in a wrong way:

```
app.after(5000, switch(thirdframe))
```

The result is the same as:

```
switch(thirdframe)
app.after(5000, None)
```

`app.after(5000, None)` works like `time.sleep(5)` so it will block tkinter main loop to update the screen until 5 seconds later.

Change it to

```
app.after(5000, switch, thirdframe)
```